# Uninitialized Constant error on Model reference in Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, rake

In my sample_data.rake file, I have the command "`Diner.create!(...)`" which causes an "`uninitialized constant Diner`" error.  However, if I execute the same "Diner.create!(...)" command in the Rails console, it is successful.  If I "require" the model in the sample_data.rake file, I get the error "`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`" with the backtrace showing "`active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:318:in retrieve_connection'`".  Here is my diner.rb file:

```
class Diner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :redemptions
  has_many  :surveys, :through => :redemptions
end
```

And the code in the sample_data.rake file that causes the problem is:

```
99.times do |n|
  gender = rand(1) == 0 ? "male" : "female"
  birthdate = Date.ordinal(DateTime.now.year - 13 - rand(62), rand(364)+1)
  Diner.create!(:gender => gender, :birthdate => birthdate)
end
```

Removing the above code causes the file to process successfully.  And, as I said earlier, the above code works correctly in rails console.

Answer (score 9):

Your rake task is clearly missing the rails environment.
If your task has the following structure and your model is within `$LOAD_PATH` then everything should be fine:

```
     namespace :yourapp do
         desc "Create sample data"
         task :populate => :environment do
           # create other data
           99.times do |n|
             gender = rand(1) == 0 ? "male" : "female"
             birthdate = Date.ordinal(DateTime.now.year - 13 - rand(62), rand(364)+1)
             Diner.create!(:gender => gender, :birthdate => birthdate)
           end
         end
     end
```

You see that `task :populate => :environment do` line, it tells rake to fire up the environment task[1] and then perform your task which now has access to your models and the Database

[1]railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb#214

[1]railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb#101

cheers

Comment: I neglected to mention that this is not the first model that I referenced in the task.  In fact, there were four different models that received records ahead of this task, and the task has completed successfully for several months before I added this new table today.  If I remove the new code the task once again works.  And I do have the "`task :populate => :environment do`" near the top of the file.

Is there anything else you can think for me to check?

Comment: Are you creating records before that `99.times` loop ?

Comment: In three other models/tables, yes.  But that is the first one in that model/table.

Comment: I just amended the problem statement to point out that I am also seeing the same error when I run "`rake routes`".

Comment: Just amended again.  "rake routes" was having a problem because the offending code was still in "sample_data.rake" -- removing the offending code solved the problem.

Comment: you say if you do `rake routes` rails/rake throws that error, meaning your `loop` lives outside of task. And therefore the environment is missing.